# clojure-solr-0.2.0 and solr4

Tags: solr, clojure, solrj

I'm trying to get clojure-solr-0.2.0 working with solr4 (trunk nightly build). I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version or the data in not in 'javabin' format
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:99)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BinaryResponseParser.processResponse(BinaryResponseParser.java:39)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:466)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:243)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:89)
```

I'm assuming this is because clojure-solr is using some version of solrj library that is from solr3 codebase and javabin format changed between versions.

Is there some easy way to get this to work?

EDIT:

I deleted solrj from my project's lib folder, and replaced it with `lib/apache-solr-solrj-4.0-2012-05-15_08-20-37.jar`. I was hoping that would just work since the same classes (should) be found on the classpath at runtime (the transitive dependency should only be required when `lein deps` is run to fetch dependencies (or so I reasoned). The result was a class not found at runtime:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader.findClass(DynamicClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at clojure_solr$eval1423$loading__4414__auto____1424.invoke(clojure_solr.clj:1)
at clojure_solr$eval1423.invoke(clojure_solr.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
... 95 more
```

And the problem is that `CommonsHttpSolrServer` is no longer present in the jar:

```
$ jar tf lib/apache-solr-solrj-4.0-2012-05-15_08-20-37.jar |grep Http
org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer$1.class
org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer$2.class
org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer$3.class
org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer$DeflateDecompressingEntity.class
org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer$GzipDecompressingEntity.class
org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer$UseCompressionRequestInterceptor.class
org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer$UseCompressionResponseInterceptor.class
org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer.class
org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/LBHttpSolrServer$1.class
org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/LBHttpSolrServer$Req.class
org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/LBHttpSolrServer$Rsp.class
org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/LBHttpSolrServer$ServerWrapper.class
org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/LBHttpSolrServer.class
$ jar tf lib/apache-solr-solrj-4.0-2012-05-15_08-20-37.jar |grep CommonsHttp
$
```

Comment: I didn't get this working, and ultimately realized that `clj-http + clj-json` is vastly simpler to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will very likely need to make your own build of clojure-solr and fix it to work with the latest solr4. This is actually not that hard.

- clone it from [the github project](https://github.com/mikejs/clojure-solr)
- lein install
- add it as a dependency in your main project
- hack and repeat.

Comment: I assume the main thing is just bumping the version of the solrj dependency, I'm almost wondering if I can just exclude solrj from clojure-solr and include my own version. And I guess to do that I can take the solrj lib from the nightly and maven install the file?

Comment: What happens if you explicitly include the version of solrj that you need? Does it win over the transitive one? Does it run ok?

Comment: I think it is only necessary to convince clojure-solr to depend on the newer solr, and that you make that version available at runtime.

Comment: marked as correct, since what you say probably does work, but as I noted in my comments, using `clj-http + clj-json` is much easier to deal with.